# Using Powershell to Detect Hotfixes AND Cumulative Updates

Tags: powershell

I'm using the Powershell commandlet "Get-Hotfix" to detect vulnerability of a given server. Here is the code:

```
if (!(get-hotfix -id KB2964444 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)) { echo "Missing!" }
```

This works perfectly, but my concern relates to cumulative updates. If a later cumulative update includes the previous hotfixes, will it be reported as `TRUE` (the correct response) or `Missing!`.

If I do a full output of `get-hotfix` (below), I don't see any cumulative updates (but cumulative ones HAVE been applied), which leads me to think that the individual ones will always be visible.

```
Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2899189_... NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/3/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2894856     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2918614     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2919355     WIN-EJ3M07TUG3E\A... 3/18/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2919442     WIN-EJ3M07TUG3E\A... 3/18/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2920189     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2931366     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2937220     WIN-EJ3M07TUG3E\A... 3/18/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2938772     WIN-EJ3M07TUG3E\A... 3/18/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2939153     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2939471     WIN-EJ3M07TUG3E\A... 3/18/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2939576     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Hotfix           KB2949621     WIN-EJ3M07TUG3E\A... 3/18/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2950153     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2954879     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/3/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2955164     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2956575     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2957189     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2958262     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Hotfix           KB2959626     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/9/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2959977     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2961072     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2962140     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2962409     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2962872     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2964718     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2964736     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2965142     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2965500     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/3/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2965788     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/3/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2966804     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2967917     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2969339     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/3/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2969817     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/7/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2971203     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2971239     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  8/13/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2971850     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2972094     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/9/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2972280     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/9/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2973201     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2973351     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2973448     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2974008     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/9/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2975061     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  7/9/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2975719     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  10/6/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2976627     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2976897     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2977629     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2977765     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2978668     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2979500     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2979582     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  10/6/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2980654     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2981580     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2981655     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2982791     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2982794     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  8/13/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2987114     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Security Update  KB2988948     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2989647     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/24/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2990532     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  10/6/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2990967     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/24/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2993100     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/24/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2993651     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/15/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2995004     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  10/6/2014 12:00:00 AM
WIN-EJ3M07... Update           KB2998527     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  9/24/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

**EDIT**
Ultimately, my question is Is there a way to query the individual hotfixes included in a cumulative update? Do the included hotfixes always show (even if a Cumulative Update has been applied)?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @NathanRice: Question is does Get-HotFixes show fixes when packaged in a CU, or just the CU.  Follow up question is: Can you drill down into a CU to see it's component fixes?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. @JohnLBevan is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing this it seems you'll get "Missing"

Checking for: KB2909921 "MS14-010: Cumulative security update for Internet Explorer: February 11, 2014" (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2909921):

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> get-hotfix -id KB2909921

Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------
MyMachine     Security Update  KB2909921     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
```

Checking for: KB2926827 "Web browser control hosting application may lose session information unexpectedly" (included in the above CU; http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2926827)

```
PS C:\Windows\System32> get-hotfix -id KB2926827
Get-HotFix : This command cannot find hot-fix on the machine 'localhost'. Verify the input and Run your command again.
At line:1 char:11
+ get-hotfix <<<<  -id KB2926827
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-HotFix], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetHotFixNoEntriesFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHotFixCommand
```

**Update**

Here's a painful hack which may help.  No guarantees, very slow, and only finds KBs which follow the current URL convention / have their HTML formatted the way my scraper assumes.
Could be improved by caching the results somewhere / perhaps used to build a reference database.

```
function get-hotfixInfo()
{
    process 
    {
        #$url = "http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/{0}" -f ($_.HotFixId -replace "KB(\d*)",'$1')
        $url = $_.Caption           
        try
        {
            $response = (Invoke-Webrequest $url -ea stop)
        } catch {
            $response = @{
                ParsedHTML = @{
                    Title = "{0}`n`nURL: {1}" -f $error[0].Exception,$url 
                }
            }
        }
        $html = $response.ParsedHTML
        $isCU = $html.title -like "*cumulative*update*"
        $kblets = $null
        if($isCU) #this bit can be even slower than the above, hence only run if we believe we have a CU
        {
            $baseUri = $response.BaseResponse.ResponseURI
            $kblets = $html.getElementsByTagName('a') `
                | ? { ($_.parentNode.tagname -eq 'TD') -and ($_.parentNode.nextsibling.tagname = 'TD') } `
                | ? { $_.className -eq 'KBlink' } `
                | % { New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Prop @{
                    Id = "KB{0}" -f $_.innerText
                    Uri = (new-object System.URIBuilder($baseUri.scheme,$baseUri.dnssafehost,$baseUri.port,($_.href -replace "about:/(.*),'$1'"))).ToString()
                    Title = $_.parentNode.nextsibling.innerText
                }}
        }
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Prop @{
            Id = $_.HotFixId
            IsCU = $isCU 
            Title = $html.title
            Source = $_.source
            Description = $_.description
            InstalledBy = $_.installedby
            InstalledOn = $_.installedon
            Uri = "http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/{0}" -f ($_.HotFixId -replace "KB(\d*)",'$1')
            KBlets = $kblets
        }
    }
}

#get the first 2 cumulative update hotfixes
get-hotfix | get-hotfixInfo | ?{$_.isCU} | select -first 2 | fl

#get the hotfix id for IE11 CU Feb 2014, and it's component hotfixes
get-hotfix -id kb2909921 | get-hotfixInfo | %{ New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Prop @{Id=$_.Id;Title=$_.Title}; $_.KBlets | %{ New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Prop @{Id=$_.Id;Title=$_.Title}}} | ft -autosize
```

Comment: Yes - I think you're right. Is there a technique for finding the hotfixes that a cumulative rolls up?

Comment: Sadly no way that I could find (programmatically).  You could search technet for all CUs and build a list of hotfixes, but that would be very painful.  Someone could build a service to provide that data which your script could query (doesn't seem to exist yet).  Ideally MS would list the actual fixes rather than the CUs they're packaged in.

Comment: Sigh. This is going to just make maintaining this stuff harder. Oh well.

Comment: ps. running `$hf = get-hotfix -id kb2909921 | get-hotfixInfo; $hf | %{$_.kblets | %{ get-hotfix -id $_.id }}` shows that none of the component hotfixes are listed.  Thought it worth checking in case one or two of the fixes in the CU weren't applicable to my machine.  Sorry :/